# ActiveRecordで指定のレコードを抽出する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

#### 現状・実現したいこと

標記の件について質問させていただきます。
【実現したいこと】

1. competition_idが同じ番号のものをまとめる
2. そのcompetition_idでグルーピングされたもののなかで、各pointsカラムが最高値のもののレコードを取得

(各competitionの1位を取得したい)

【現状】
現在、DBにはitemsテーブルとcompetitionsテーブルがあります。
カラムや格納されているデータについては以下の通りです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

○itemsテーブルには、そのitemが持つpointsがある。
○itemsテーブルには、どのcompetitionに属しているかを指定するcompetiton_idが存在している。

#### 試したこと

```
Item.maximum("points")
最大値が出力されただけで、レコードの出力をしたい
```

```
Item.order("points DESC")
グルーピングされていなく、pointsの降順で取得された
```

```
Item.order("points DESC").group(:competition_id) 
pointsの最高値のレコード（希望している結果）ではなく、competition_idの初めのレコードを取得された
```

いろいろと試行錯誤してみましたが、希望通りの抽出ができません。
上記のレコードを抽出するActiveRecordをご教授いただければ幸いです。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

- ruby 2.7.0p0
- Rails 6.1.0
- sqlite

Answer (score 0):

下記の通り、自己解決しました

```
query = "SELECT *,MAX(points) FROM Items GROUP BY competition_id"

@winners = Item.find_by_sql(query)
```